# Is there a library/function in python that can be resample multichannel audio files i.e higher than stereo?

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing

I'm working with 4 channel audio and I want to downsample it from 48kHz to 44.1kHz (as an example). Usually, I'd use `librosa.resample()` however AFAIK it only handles up to 2 channels. Anyone got any suggestions?

I had thought of taking a channel at a time and passing it through the librosa function - but that seems a bit of a faff and I'd like a neater way of doing it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [scipy.io.wavfile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html) for I/O then resample the channels independently with the method you already know.

```py
x = np.random.randn(1600, 10) / 8;
wavfile.write('multi-channel.wav', 1600, x); # save a 10-channel wave file
sample_rate, X_read =  wavfile.read('multi-channel.wav')
```